# Парсинг Avito

Tags: .net, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: на Avito есть кнопка "показать телефон", при нажатии на неё загружается картинка с телефоном, посылается GET запрос на

```
http://www.avito.ru/items/phone/odintsovo_noutbuki_noutbuk_asus_f3s_65506634?pkey=ece88f80e462d5eeb4b29a1de63f9273
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить переменную `pkey` или как иначе получить телефон?

ЯП - семейства NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В теле страницы есть строка типа:

```
<meta name="ph_ver" content="27ad43190y74ce6451b5c2a64f76y92dy00869f0f90805d92f06f1d48y49dye1fa0fy784y246dc4fd2ye46d2cab1y367y609534ca7" />
```

Копать нужно здесь: искать в скриптах, каким образом эта строка конвертируется в ключ типа:

```
4f3537fc35be909923b193abcd3a0e91
```

Похоже здесь закопано вычисление хэша.

До кучи: http://pumanet.codeplex.com/ - собственно распознавалка.

Comment: О! Спасибо огромное за ссылку на распознавалку!

Answer (score 0):

Из нее по регулярке выбираются определенные символы и реверс идет + четность - нечетность.